LibHaru doesn't save embedded fonts to stream
I'm writing some wrapper library around LibHaru and want clients to control output themselves. In my library I'm embedding some TTF fonts.
Pdf::Pdf(std::string fontFilename, HPDF_REAL fontSize)
{
  pdf_ = HPDF_New(
    [](HPDF_STATUS error_no, HPDF_STATUS detail_no, void *user_data) {
      throw PdfException(error_no, detail_no);
    },
    NULL
  );
  if (!pdf_) {
    throw PdfException("cannot create PdfDoc object");
  }

  const auto fontName = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(pdf_, fontFilename.c_str(), HPDF_TRUE);
  font_ = HPDF_GetFont(pdf_, fontName, NULL);
}

void Pdf::dump(std::ostream & os) const
{
  const auto saveStatus = HPDF_SaveToStream(pdf_);
  if (saveStatus != HPDF_OK) {
    throw PdfException(saveStatus, saveStatus);
  }
  HPDF_ResetStream(pdf_);

  for (;;) {
    HPDF_BYTE buf[4096];
    HPDF_UINT32 siz = 4096;
    HPDF_STATUS ret = HPDF_ReadFromStream (pdf_, buf, &siz);

    if (siz == 0)
        break;

    os << buf;
  }
}

void Pdf::dumpToFile(cosnt std::string filename)
{
  HPDF_SaveToFile(pdf_, filename.c_str());
}

When I'm using Pdf::dumpToFile method to persist PDF -- everything correct. If I'm using Pdf::dump method with std::ofstream -- the file is 9Kb smaller and not opening. Trying to debug the difference with xxd found out, that font information is lacking. Is there a way to write the whole PDF to stream properly?
